# Would someone mind helping me understand why my function isn't producing correct results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I wanted to find the sum of two arrays in JavaScript at the same index location (ex. arr1[0] + arr2[0], arr1[1] + arr2 [1],...). I created a function to do so but for some reason it is only adding the first array entry correctly. here is the code:

```
var nums = [566646, 71109, 630748, 804254, 672665, 266232, 127182];
var nums2 = [951445, 884541, 171744, 721337, 609206, 237856, 290200];
var numsLength= nums.length;
var i;
var sum = 0;

function test() {
    for(i=0; i < numsLength; i++) {
        sum += (nums[i] + nums2[i]);
        console.log(sum);
    };
}


test();
```

Comment: what output you get after execution

Comment: You're accumulating the sums into `sum` instead of building a new array with the individual sums. Is that your intent?

Comment: What output do you expect, and what output do you see?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?

Comment: yea sorry guys it was a bit bone-headed of me not to post my results. also I see now the "+=" was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print sum for each array index you need not to accumulate as `sum+=` the sum will change every time, what you were doing was cumulative

```
index0 > sum = arr1[0] + arr2[0]
index1 > sum = arr1[0] + arr2[0] + arr1[1] + arr2[1]
index2 > sum = arr1[0] + arr2[0] + arr1[1] + arr2[1] + arr1[2] + arr2[2]
...
```

rather than only sum for the current index

```
function test() {
    for(i=0; i < numsLength; i++) {
        sum = (nums[i] + nums2[i]); 
        console.log(sum);
    };
}
```

Comment: OK i see where I went wrong thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`sum += (nums[i] + nums2[i]);`

should be

```
sum = (nums[i] + nums2[i]);
//  ^ - here
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as I understand, you want an output-array containing, for each index, the sum of the values of the input-arrays for the same index, it should look like this:

```
for(i=0; i < numsLength; i++) {
    sum[i] = (nums[i] + nums2[i]);
};
console.log(sum);/*logs the whole output-array to the console*/
```

(Note: I also replaced the `+=`by an `=`: as explained in preceding answers, `+=` sums with the actual value of the variable on the left side of the operator - which results in a cumulated sum of all array-entries of both input-arrays in your code.)

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is the line

> sum += (nums[i] + nums2[i]);

+= will sum the previous value of 'sum' to the new value.

it's the same as :

> sum = sum + (nums[i] + nums2[i]);

```
var nums = [566646, 71109, 630748, 804254, 672665, 266232, 127182];
 var nums2 = [951445, 884541, 171744, 721337, 609206, 237856, 290200];
 var numsLength= nums.length;
 var i;
  var sum = 0;

function test() {
   for(i=0; i < numsLength; i++) {
    sum = (nums[i] + nums2[i]);
    console.log(sum);
   };
}


test();
```